# function in HREF not working using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have function which needs to be run on click event. However it is working fine with onclick attribute of anchor tag but not working with HREF attribute. It is giving id undefined. Here is demo code

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:test(this)" id="first">click</a>
```

**JS**

```
function test(obj){
alert(obj.id)
}
```

Comment: `this` in that context is the `window`, not the control. It's not the same an event handler. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/zv2Jp/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in that context is the `window`, not the control. Placing javascript in the `href` is not the same as an event handler like `onclick`. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/zv2Jp/).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fix:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:test(this);" id="first">click</a>
```

Comment: `javascript:` is not necessary in an inline event handler.

Comment: @Thiago: I know the fix I already mention that in my question. But my question is WHY it is not working.

Comment: @amit sorry. I read fast so I just rewrote your function "test" so that it could access id property of your anchor...but I believe that canon already answered the reason above. Let me know if I could do anything for you. best regards

Answer (score 2):

This question already got answers but if you want to use a function as you used in your question then you should use it like

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://heera.it" onclick="return test(this.id)" id="first">click</a>
```

**JS:**

```
function test(obj){
    alert(obj);
    return false; // this is required to stop navigation to that link
}
```

notice, `return false`, if you have value in `href` like this example, then you should use `return false` but there are other options like `event.preventDefault()` or `event.returnValue = false (for IE)` for this reason.

[DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/zv2Jp/) Another [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/zv2Jp/3/) (without `return false`). Read about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

I enjoyed [Matt Kruse's Javascript Best Practices](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/) article. In it, he states that using the `href` section to execute `JavaScript` code is a bad idea.

here are some good practices to call javascript on anchor:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="return DoSomething();">link</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="return DoSomething();">link</a>
<a href="#" onClick="return DoSomething();">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onclick event of the anchor tag. this inside href represents current window.